# How can I set the column width in a spreadsheet to a specific pixel count (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, pixel, aspose, column-width, aspose-cells

I am setting the width of a column this way:

```
private static readonly int RESTAURANT_LOCATION_COLUMN_WIDTH = 28;
. . .
deliveryPerformanceWorksheet.Column(RESTAURANT_LOCATION_COLUMN).Width = RESTAURANT_LOCATION_COLUMN_WIDTH;
```

The end user wants the width to be precisely 225 pixels.

The width value is obviously not in pixels; is there some calculation for converting the value used to pixels to cause the value assigned to equate to a specific pixel count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as eating gooseberry pie:

```
deliveryPerformanceWorksheet.Cells.SetColumnWidthPixel(RESTAURANT_LOCATION_COLUMN, 225);
```